# How to handle onClick from side menu in different fragments

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Ok so i have side menu and whenever is clicked it should call some code from specific fragment,I put NavigationView in MainActivity and so when i try to call it in my fragment obviously i will get NullPointerException because is not in the same layout as my fragments.I am using data binding and Navigation.

so bassicaly i tried this:  `NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.nav_view); navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`
in my on create in fragment and get NullPointerException ,and i know why so please do not post me what is this error.

and later again in my fragment i would this:

```
   @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.history_TV) {
        viewModel.myAssetsResponse().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), this::consumeResponse);
        viewModel.getAssets();
    }
    return true;
}
```

And that does not work because i can not attach listener to something that is not in my fragment layout.
i have about seven fragments and every one of them should implement different code when same item on side menu is clicked. How to accomplish that?

Comment: let your fragments implement `interface HistoryExecutor { void Show(); }`  ... in `MainActivity` when history menu is cliecked check current active fragment and if it implements `HistoryExecutor`  call `Show` of it ...

Comment: Your fragment should be created in order to call some code on it.